# Calculate colordifference

Tags: php

Is it possible to check if a certain hexadecimal color is closer to FFF or 000 based on a defined 'center-value'?

I want to check if a color lies closer to #FFF or #000 based on #888. 
So if I check for #EFEFEF it should return #FFF and if I try #878787 it should return #000.

How can this be achieved? I'm not sure what to search for on Google...

Thanks in advance

Comment: isn't #898989 higher than #888 (#888888) and thus should return #fff? #878787 should be the highes value that return #000 in my opinion...

Comment: You need to decide on how the [distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_difference) should be calculated.

Comment: @oezi: He wants to use #888 as a bias reference color, meaning that what he really wants to do is compare a color between #888 and #FFF, and return either #000 or #FFF depending on which is closer (basically return #000 if the color is closer to #888 than to #FFF).

Comment: Indeed I made a little mistake in my post, I meant #878787, not #898989. I've changed it so it might be clear to others as well. Thanks everybody!

Comment: Now you left me confused, is #898989 supposed to return #000 or #FFF? Because my answer (which you accepted), assumed that it's supposed to return #000 (because it's closer to #888 than to #FFF). If it should've returned #FFF instead, then you can get rid of the whole $refColor(Min|Max) stuff, and just have it calculate distances to $minColor ans $maxColor directly.

Comment: You are correct, I've changed my typo in the question and provided an answer myself to. But you deserver the credits ;) I've tweeked your function a small bit to get what I needed. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to solve your problem is to calculate the distance between colors using their greyscale values (there are other ways, but this is simple). So something like:

```
// returns a distance between two colors by comparing each component
// using average of the RGB components, eg. a grayscale value
function color_distance($a, $b)
{
    $decA = hexdec(substr($a, 1));
    $decB = hexdec(substr($a, 1));
    $avgA = (($decA & 0xFF) + (($decA >> 8) & 0xFF) + (($decA >> 16) & 0xFF)) / 3;
    $avgB = (($decB & 0xFF) + (($decB >> 8) & 0xFF) + (($decB >> 16) & 0xFF)) / 3;
    return abs($avgA - $avgB);
}

// I am going to leave the naming of the function to you ;)
// How this works is that it'll return $minColor if $color is closer to $refColorMin
// and $maxColor if $color is closer to $refColorMax
// all colors should be passed in format #RRGGBB
function foo($color, $refColorMin, $refColorMax, $minColor, $maxColor)
{
    $distMin = color_distance($color, $refColorMin);
    $distMax = color_distance($color, $refColorMax);
    return ($distMin < $distMax) ? $minColor : $maxColor;
}

// Example usage to answer your original question:
$colorA = foo('#EFEFEF', '#888888', '#FFFFFF', '#000000', '#FFFFFF');
$colorA = foo('#898989', '#888888', '#FFFFFF', '#000000', '#FFFFFF');
// Check the values
var_dump($colorA, $colorB);
```

The output is:

```
string(7) "#FFFFFF"
string(7) "#000000"
```

Answer (score 3):

You could convert the colours to numbers:

```
$color_num = hexdec(substr($color, 1)); // skip the initial #
```

Then compare them to either `0x0` or `0xffffff`.

You could also break them down into R, G and B and make three comparisons; then average them? Not sure how precise you want this thing :)

Comment: Comparing the converted decimal values directly is not a good idea, as the bits stored for some components have higher values than the components for others. So for example if the red bits were stored in the highest order bits, and blue bits in lowest order bits, the red bits would weight more than the blue and green bits overall, which would not give very accurate results at all. Your idea of using an average is good; it's what I used in my answer as well.

Comment: @reko_t good point :) your answer is substantially more worked out than mine hehe

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like the following:

```
function hex2rgb($hex) {
   $hex = str_replace("#", "", $hex);

   if(strlen($hex) == 3) {
      $r = hexdec(substr($hex,0,1).substr($hex,0,1));
      $g = hexdec(substr($hex,1,1).substr($hex,1,1));
      $b = hexdec(substr($hex,2,1).substr($hex,2,1));
   } else {
      $r = hexdec(substr($hex,0,2));
      $g = hexdec(substr($hex,2,2));
      $b = hexdec(substr($hex,4,2));
   }
   $rgb = array($r, $g, $b);
   //return implode(",", $rgb); // returns the rgb values separated by commas
   return $rgb; // returns an array with the rgb values
}

$rgb = hex2rgb("#cc0");
```

From that you could take the values of $rgb and see if their values, on average, area greater than or less than 122.5. If its greater than 122.5 you'd be closer to #FFFFFF, lower than 122.5 you'd be closer to #000000.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everybody for the help!

In my startpost I made a little typo as mentioned by oezi. For me the solution was a small modification to the accepted answer (by reko_t):

```
function color_distance($sColor1, $sColor2)
{
    $decA = hexdec(substr($sColor1, 1));
    $decB = hexdec(substr($sColor2, 1));
    $avgA = (($decA & 0xFF) + (($decA >> 8) & 0xFF) + (($decA >> 16) & 0xFF)) / 3;
    $avgB = (($decB & 0xFF) + (($decB >> 8) & 0xFF) + (($decB >> 16) & 0xFF)) / 3;
    return abs($avgA - $avgB);
}

function determine_color($sInputColor, $sRefColor, $sMinColor, $sMaxColor)
{
    $distRef    = color_distance($sInputColor, $sRefColor);
    $distMin    = color_distance($sInputColor, $sMinColor);
    $distMax    = color_distance($sInputColor, $sMaxColor);

    return $distMax - $distRef <  $distMin - $distRef ? $sMinColor : $sMaxColor;
}
```

I needed this function to determine text-color on a background-color which can be set by some setting. Thanks! :) Credits to reko_t!